# Get value of multidimensional array in array

Tags: php, laravel, forms, multidimensional-array, repeater

I have below values in formsubmit,

```
items[0][item_name]: Test
items[0][item_description]: testing1
items[0][item_price]: 11
items[0][item_group]: 18
items[0][item_code]: 11
items[0][item_is_active][]: 1
items[1][item_name]: test2
items[1][item_description]: test
items[1][item_price]: 12
items[1][item_group]: 18
items[1][item_code]: 12
items[1][item_is_active][]: 1
```

and here is serverside DB entry in laravel,

```
            $items_data = $request->items;

            foreach ($items_data as $i) {
                $items = new Menuitems; //Must be reinit to reiterate all entries
                $items->item_name = $i['item_name'];
                $items->item_description = $i['item_description'];
                $items->item_price = $i['item_price'];
                $items->item_group = $i['item_group'];
                $items->item_code = $i['item_code'];
                $items->item_is_active = $i['item_is_active'];
                $items->save();
            }
```

It works fine all entries except for **item_is_active** because it has one more **[ ]** in form input,

How can I add **item_is_active** in foreach loop? should it have one more foreach loop inside?

---

Below is formsubmit values when some checkboxes are not selected,

```
items[0][item_name]: Capachno
items[0][item_description]: best
items[0][item_price]: 12
items[0][item_group]: 17
items[0][item_code]: 11
items[0][item_is_active][]: 1
items[1][item_name]: Lambc
items[1][item_description]: sdf
items[1][item_price]: 34
items[1][item_group]: 17
items[1][item_code]: 12
items[1][item_is_active][]: 1
items[2][item_name]: tasto
items[2][item_description]: ewr
items[2][item_price]: 12
items[2][item_group]: 17
items[2][item_code]: 13
items[3][item_name]: hingo
items[3][item_description]: 123
items[3][item_price]: 123
items[3][item_group]: 17
items[3][item_code]: 32
```

Comment: `item_is_active` is going to have many values or just one value?

Comment: @nice_dev, it is a checkbox, so either it has value=1 or no value.

Comment: you could try to point it directly to index zero, but the much sensible approach is to just remove the extra square bracket in `name="items[1][item_is_active][]"` on the html markup. then on PHP side, you'll just access it just like the rest.

Comment: @rjcode, if it's a (single) checkbox, then why do you make it an array?

Comment: @RoAchterberg, it is default coming from formrepeater, https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater

Comment: $i['item_is_active'][0] - it's array so just use it as one